# Android Scanner Delimiter Issues

Tags: android, string, text, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Ok, the other day I had trouble with the FileWriter notding the newline, but I got some help with that and solved it. Now, just like before, I cpoied some old code of mine (works perfectly in the old prgram) to read the file that's written. I use "|" as a delimiter (pieces.useDelimiter("|");). When I call pieces.next() it only teakes the next character, not the next string up to the delimiter. What am I missing?
Code snippet:

```
try{
    mFile = new Scanner(newFile(loadPath));
    while(mFile.hasNextLine()){
        String input = mFile.nextLine();
        Scanner pieces = new Scanner(input);
        pieces.useDelimiter("|");
        while(pieces.hasNext()){
            int row = Integer.valueOf(pieces.next());
            int col = Integer.valueOf(pieces.next());
            String pullPath = pieces.next();
            ......
```

}}

Comment: Please post some code for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String that you pass to [useDelimiter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) is interpreted as a regular expression. `|` is a special character in regular expressions, so you have to escape it with a backslash. And the backslash itself needs to be escaped, in order to get past the Java compiler. So changing that line as follows should do the trick:

```
    pieces.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

Also, note that the string returned by `pieces.next()` includes the delimiter. I suspect that these lines:

```
        int row = Integer.valueOf(pieces.next());
        int col = Integer.valueOf(pieces.next());
```

could be replaced by:

```
        int row = pieces.nextInt();
        int col = pieces.nextInt();
```

You may also need to adjust `pullPath` to trim the delimiter(s).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot! do you have any links to info on escaping? I've never come across it befre...

Comment: @weh: Try http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#101089 for the standard Java string literal syntax, and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for regular expression syntax (see the section "Backslashes, escapes, and quoting".)